# Powershell with Word CheckSpelling and selected dictionary

Tags: powershell, dictionary, com, ms-word, spell-checking

I would like to spell check some strings using the Microsoft Word API in Powershell and a specific dictionary ("English (US)").
I use the following code to do the checking but it does not seem to take into account the dictionary I want. Any ideas what is wrong? Also, command "New-Object -COM Word.Dictionary" seems to fail.

```
$word = New-Object -COM Word.Application
$dictionary = New-Object -COM Word.Dictionary

foreach ($language in $word.Languages) {
    if ($language.Name.Contains("English (US)")) {
        $dictionary = $language.ActiveSpellingDictionary;
        break;
    }
}

Write-Host $dictionary.Name

$check = $word.CheckSpelling("Color", [ref]$null, [ref]$null, [ref]$dictionary)
if(!$check) {
    Write-Host "Spelling Error!"
}

$word.quit()
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | Out-Null
Remove-Variable word
```

Comment: have you tried setting your dictionary as custom dictionary (2nd param) and leave the rest out?

Comment: I tried, but I get:
"Exception calling "CheckSpelling" with "13" argument(s)" etc...

Comment: have you tried the code i postet below?

Comment: I added a comment there as well.

Answer (score 2):

The COMobject word.dictionary does not exist (at least not on my machine), here is what worked for me in the short test i did:

```
$dic = New-Object -COM Scripting.Dictionary #credits to MickyB
$w = New-Object -COM Word.Application
$w.Languages | % {if($_.Name -eq "English (US)"){$dic=$_.ActiveSpellingDictionary}}
$w.checkSpelling("Color", [ref]$null, [ref]$null, [ref]$dic)
```

Comment: This indeed does not give any errors. However, "Color" appears to be false on my machine. I have "English (UK)" as default in my machine. When I use "English (US)" it should return true, right? It seems CheckSpelling accepts the argument but is not using it.

Comment: Yes the spellchecking is weird, especially since on my machine both English US and UK return true for "Color" and false for "Colour". I  inspected my $dic object and it seems that it uses the same dictionary file (MSSP7EN.LEX) for both, what file do your dic objects use?

Comment: Interesting, I seem to be getting the same results as you: MSSP7EN.LEX

Comment: hmm, in word itself i can only get the spell checking to work if i mark the text and declare it is either enUS or enUK but as far as i see there is no option to set this here. i´m out of ideas for now

Comment: if you only have to check a limited number of words you could create a custom dictionary, what is the source of your words?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility in addition to Paul's:

```
$dictionary = New-Object -COM Scripting.Dictionary
```

Comment: yep this would be the correct variable declaration, lazy me just left it to powershell

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same problem, that the `Word.Application.checkSpelling()` method seems to ignore any dictionary passed to it. I worked around the issue creating a Word document, defining a text range, changing the LanguageID of this range to the language I want to proof read against, and then inspecting detected spelling errors. Here is the code:

```
<#Function which helps to pick the language#>
function FindLanguage($language_name){    
    foreach($element in $Word.Languages){
        if($element.Name -eq $language_name){
            $element.Name
            return $element
        }
    }
}
$Proofread_text = "The lazie frog jumpss over over the small dog."
$Word = New-Object -COM Word.Application
$Document = $Word.Documents.Add()
$Textrange = $Document.Range(0)

$english = FindLanguage("English (US)")

$Textrange.LanguageID = $english.ID
$Textrange.InsertAfter($Proofread_text)

<#Handle misspelled words here#>
foreach($spell_error in $textrange.SpellingErrors){
    Write-Host $spell_error.Text    
}

$Document.Close(0)
$Word.Quit()
```

The output will be:

```
>>lazie
>>jumpss
>>over
```

I found it helpful to disable the language autodetection in word before starting the script. Especially when you plan to switch the language.